# Where is PCB on Linux

Tags: linux, process, cpu

A PCB or *process control block*, is defined like this on Wikipedia

> Process Control Block (PCB, also called Task Controlling Block,[1]
>   Task Struct, or Switchframe) is a data structure in the operating
>   system kernel containing the information needed to manage a particular
>   process. The PCB is "the manifestation of a process in an operating
>   system

and its duty is:

```
Process identification data
Processor state data
Process control data
```

So where can the PCB of a process be found?

Comment: Also see [Process control block in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8162956/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Linux kernel, each process is represented by a [`task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/task_struct) in a doubly-linked list, the head of which is [`init_task`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/init_task) (pid 0, not pid 1).  This is commonly known as the *process table*.

In user mode, the process table is visible to normal users under `/proc`.  Taking the headings for your question:

- **Process identification data** is the process ID (which is in the path `/proc/<process-id>/...`), the command line (`cmd`), and possibly other attributes depending on your definition of 'identification'.
- **Process state data** includes scheduling data (`sched`, `stat` and `schedstat`), what the process is currently waiting on (`wchan`), its environment (`environ`) etc.
- **Process control data** could be said to be its credentials (`uid_map`) and resource limits (`limits`).

So it all depends how you define your terms... but in general, all data about a process can be found in `/proc`.

Comment: "the head of which is `init_task` (pid 0, not pid 1)" There's no such thing as `init_task`. It's `init`, and its pid is 1, not 0 (confirmed via `pidof init`).

Comment: @AleksandrH init_task is a kernel structure and not a process. It points to the idle task which is internally represented by pid 0. init_task and init are completely different things.

Comment: And yet `pid` is only for processes...

Comment: @AleksandrH Read init/init_task.c in the kernel source tree (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/init_task.c).

Answer (score 0):

PCB in linux is part of [thread_info](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/thread_info.h#L15) struct

```
struct thread_info {
struct pcb_struct   pcb;        /* palcode state */

struct task_struct  *task;      /* main task structure */
unsigned int        flags;      /* low level flags */
unsigned int        ieee_state; /* see fpu.h */

mm_segment_t        addr_limit; /* thread address space */
unsigned        cpu;        /* current CPU */
int         preempt_count; /* 0 => preemptable, <0 => BUG */
unsigned int        status;     /* thread-synchronous flags */

int bpt_nsaved;
unsigned long bpt_addr[2];      /* breakpoint handling  */
unsigned int bpt_insn[2];};


struct pcb_struct {
unsigned long ksp; - Kernel Stack Pointer
unsigned long usp; - User stack Pointer
unsigned long ptbr; - Page table address
unsigned int pcc;
unsigned int asn;
unsigned long unique;
unsigned long flags;
unsigned long res1, res2;};
```